# getting java.lang.nosuchmethoderror no virtual method execute when use android studio

Tags: android, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am getting java.lang.nosuchmethoderror no virtual method execute error now after change the compile version to 23 in android studio

please check my gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':gestureimageview')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-hipmob-2.9.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/HockeySDK-3.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.2v1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')

    compile group: 'com.zopim.android', name: 'sdk', version: '1.1.0', changing: false
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

can anyone help please?

**EDIT**

The versions that I am using are

- httpclient-4.3
- httpcore-4.3
- httpmime-4.3

and the full stacktrace is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute
at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search I found that

org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute method is deprecated in version 22, and completely removed in version 23

and to solve this problem I use HttpURLConnection instead

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html